# Bad contact on USB port in daily use

Tags: usb, physical-wear

I've got my passwords saved in a keepass container on an USB stick and use it at home and at work, therefore plugging it daily. Most USB ports develop a visible loose-fit, and unmounts on touching the stick, e.g. when using a neighboring port.

Is there something I can do to improve the (physical) life-time of USB ports?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excluding the obvious answer "Do not plug and unplug that often", there is a "Do not plug and unplug that often **on that port**". E.g. by using an USB to USB cable.

The downside for that is that you need one cable per location.
The upside is that you can put the pen drive with precious information somewhat out of sight.

Comment: One could also purchase a USB 2.0/3.0 External Hub.  This means the only the external hub will see wear, which can easily be replaced.

Comment: Well, a usb cable is cheaper than replacing/fixing the PC. I'll try that...

Answer (score 2):

You can apply some superglue to the case and USB port connection to keep it from moving.